# Json.Net fails to serialize to a stream, but works just fine serializing to a string

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

Internally, `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Formatting.Indented)` boils down to

```
JsonSerializer jsonSerializer = JsonSerializer.Create(null);
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter(new StringBuilder(256), (IFormatProvider) CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
using (JsonTextWriter jsonTextWriter = new JsonTextWriter((TextWriter) stringWriter))
{
  jsonTextWriter.Formatting = formatting;
  jsonSerializer.Serialize((JsonWriter) jsonTextWriter, value);
}
return stringWriter.ToString();
```

This works just fine. However, if I do the following:

```
string json;

JsonSerializer jsonSerializer = JsonSerializer.Create();

using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
using (var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(streamWriter))
{
    serializer.Serialize(jsonWriter, cmd);

    stream.Position = 0;
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        json = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Then the value of `json` is `""`. Can anyone point me to my mistake?

Comment: try calling Flush() on writer;

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem is that you haven't flushed the `streamWriter` after writing:

```
serializer.Serialize(jsonWriter, cmd);
streamWriter.Flush();
stream.Position = 0;
```

Alternatively, why not just use a `StringWriter` to start with?

```
using (var writer = new StringWriter())
{
    using (var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(writer))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(jsonWriter, cmd);
        Console.WriteLine(writer.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Aha! It *was* the missing Flush. Thanks. As for the stream vs. string thing, I'm not actually interested in a string representation. I am being passed a stream that I need to fill. However, I originally did a test using strings just so I would know what I was getting into, and when the comparable stream version didn't work, I got confused.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that either `JsonTextWriter` or `StreamWriter` do some internal buffering. So try to flush the `jsonWriter` and/or the `streamWriter` before reading from the underlying memory stream.